# Netty 4.0 HTTP Chunks memory leaks?

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to make HTTP Transfer Encoding Chunked work with Netty 4.0.

I had success with it so far. It works well with small payloads.

Then I tried with large data, it started to hang.

I suspect there might be a problem with my code, or maybe a leak with ByteBuf.copy().

I stripped down my code to the bare minimum to be sure that I had no other source of leak or side effect and I've ended down to write this test. [The complete code is here.](https://gist.github.com/codingtony/6566869/6d24c3aa1c8c815a66777a09d2f89ef4380ee593)

Basically it sends 1GB of 0x0 when you connect with wget to port 8888. I reproduce the problem when I connect with

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:8888 -O /dev/null
```

Here's the handler :

```
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpMessage msg) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
        HttpHeaders.setTransferEncodingChunked(response);
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
        ctx.write(response);

        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();
        int GIGABYTE = (4 * 1024 * 1024); // multiply 256B = 1GB
        for (int i = 0; i < GIGABYTE; i++) {
            buf.writeBytes(CONTENT_256BYTES_ZEROED);
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultHttpContent(buf.copy()));
            buf.clear();
           }
           ctx.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my approach?

**EDIT :**

With VisualVM I've found that there is a memory leak in the `ChannelOutboundBuffer`.

The  `Entry[] buffer` keeps growing, `addCapacity()` is called multiple times. The `Entry` array seems to contains copies of the buffers that are (or should) be written to the wire.

I see with wireshark data coming in...

Here's a Dropbox link to the [heapdump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ochhmturvl97elz/netty_at_hang.bin.bz2?m)

Comment: It's with 4.0.8 Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was doing wrong.

The `for` loop that `writeAndFlush()` was not working well and is likely to be cause of the leak.

I tried various things (see many revisions in the gist link). [See the gist version at the time of writing.](https://gist.github.com/codingtony/6566869/f90f0233d30ed02b3374ee0e17792ccc940a3549)

I have found out that the best way to achieve what I wanted to do without memory leaks was to extends InputStream and write to the context (not using `writeAndFlush()`) the InputStream wrapped in an `io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedStream`.

```
    DefaultHttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
    HttpHeaders.setTransferEncodingChunked(response);
    response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
    ctx.write(response);
    InputStream is = new InputStream() {
      int offset = -1;
      byte[] buffer = null;


      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
          if (offset == -1 || (buffer != null && offset == buffer.length)) {
            fillBuffer();
          }
          if (buffer == null || offset == -1) {
            return -1;
          }
          while (offset < buffer.length) {
            int b = buffer[offset];
            offset++;
            return b;
          }
          return -1;
      }

      // this method simulates an application that would write to
      // the buffer.

      // ONE GB (max size for the test;
      int sz = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 

      private void fillBuffer() {
        offset = 0;
        if (sz <= 0) { // LIMIT TO ONE GB
            buffer = null;
            return;
        }
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        System.arraycopy(CONTENT_1KB_ZEROED, 0,
                buffer, 0,
                CONTENT_1KB_ZEROED.length);
        sz -= 1024;
      }
};


ctx.write(new ChunkedStream(new BufferedInputStream(is), 8192));
ctx.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

The code is writing 1GB of data to the client in 8K chunks. I was able to run 30 simultaneous connection without memory or hanging problems.