Memory leak in netty writeAndFlush
I'm currently developing a java package similar to .net signalr that utilizes netty. As I tried to benchmark it I realized that there's a memory leak in my application. I narrowed down my search to the section where I write the result of the client request back to the TCP channel. Code below is where the memory leak is happening.
private ChannelFuture writeMessageInternal(Message message) {
        ByteBuf buf;
        Codec codec = message.getCodec();
        try {
            buf = codec.encode(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(buf);
        return channelFuture;
    }

If I comment ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(buf); and change the code like:
private ChannelFuture writeMessageInternal(Message message) {
        ByteBuf buf;
        Codec codec = message.getCodec();
        try {
            buf = codec.encode(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        // ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(buf);
        return null;
    }

then no memory leak happens. buf is an unpooled bytebuf so it didn't require to be released manually.
Currently java 21 and netty-all of version 4.1.58.Final is benig used.

There's little sense in reporting it here - report it as a GitHub issue. Assuming it's in Netty's module, this is the link: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues

I couldn't find the declaration of variable channel that appears in this line of your code: ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(buf); My guess is that the problem is in your use of variable channel. Since the declaration of channel doesn't appear in the code of method writeMessageInternal, I'm guessing that it is a class attribute and is referenced in other methods. Maybe you need to do something with that attribute that you are not doing and that is causing the memory leak. It may be considered a "resource leak" rather than a memory leak.

Even unpooled bytebufs need to be released. Unpooled array based ones do not requite releasing, but it is still recommended

Maybe relates https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807751/7508077

In languages like Java and C# one of the only ways to create memory leaks is to not correctly handling the resources managed by OS. Other than that, I believe this benchmark has real flaws as it seems you are running both clients and server on the same machine. You also didn’t mention the OS name. These are all important factors.
